# Is it possible to Change Ant designs theme as dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there any way available to change Ant design theme during runtime in react 16.7 CRA.
Config-overides.js file looks like this

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports } = require('customize-cra');

 module.exports = override(
   fixBabelImports('import', {
     libraryName: 'antd',
     libraryDirectory: 'es',
     style: 'css',
   }),
addLessLoader({
   javascriptEnabled: true,
   modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' },
 })
 );
```

This code changes the color as static but How can I make it as dynamic

Comment: maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@mzohaib.qc/ant-design-dynamic-runtime-theme-1f9a1a030ba0) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is now possible with [antd-theme-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzohaibqc/antd-theme-webpack-plugin). You can see in the source code of the [live demo how it works](https://github.com/mzohaibqc/antd-theme-webpack-plugin/blob/master/examples/antd-init/index.js) (by calling `window.less.modifyVars(vars)`).

As stated in the repository, the webpack plugin injects a javascript file that allows you so your application can act like it dynamically modifies less variables. Also note that, as stated in the repo, if your webpack does not generate the HTML you need to manually modify it to include the library and proper `script` files.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement this is to make another set of css only for the dark mode, and to scope them.

The less compiler handles this somehow, but you need to be extra careful in the order of feeding less files for compilation in your code. You might need to try and error for this. The basic idea is:

```
import './styles/dark.less';
import './styles/index.less';
```

in the dark.less you will have more or less

```
[data-theme^="dark"] {
  @import "./your.less";   
}
```

Now you can select the mode dynamically by assigning the value in your root html tag. 
As for this, this link might be helpful: https://medium.com/missive-app/make-your-electron-app-dark-mode-compatible-c23dcfdd0dfa